# RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.1'

Tags: conda, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

### Description.

While trying to use pre-commit hooks, I am experiencing some difficulties, including [the latest Lava-nc release by Intel in `.tar.gz` format](https://github.com/lava-nc/lava/releases/download/v0.3.0/lava-nc-0.3.0.tar.gz) `pip` package in a Conda environment.

### MWE

The following Conda `environment.yaml` file is used:

```
# This file is to automatically configure your environment. It allows you to
# run the code with a single command without having to install anything
# (extra).

# First run:: conda env create --file environment.yml
# If you change this file, run: conda env update --file environment.yml

# Instructions for this networkx-to-lava-nc repository only. First time usage
# On Ubuntu (this is needed for lava-nc):
# sudo apt upgrade
# sudo apt full-upgrade
# yes | sudo apt install gcc

# Conda configuration settings. (Specify which modules/packages are installed.)
name: networkx-to-lava
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - conda
dependencies:
- anaconda
- conda:
# Run python tests.
  - pytest-cov
- pip
- pip:
# Run pip install on .tar.gz file in GitHub repository (For lava-nc only).
  - https://github.com/lava-nc/lava/releases/download/v0.3.0/lava-nc-0.3.0.tar.gz
# Auto check static typing.
  - mypy
# Auto check programming style aspects.
  - pylint
```

If I include the following MWE `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
# Test if the variable typing is correct
# - repo: https://github.com/python/mypy
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
   rev: v0.950
   hooks:
    - id: mypy
```

### Output/Error Message

The `git commit "something"` and the `pre-commit run --all-files` return both:

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/bin/python3.1', '-mvirtualenv', '/home/name/.cache/pre-commit/repolk_aet_q/py_env-python3.1', '-p', 'python3.1')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.1'
    
stderr: (none)
Check the log at /home/name/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

### Error Log.

The output of `pre-commit.log` is:

```
### version information


pre-commit version: 2.19.0
git --version: git version 2.30.2
sys.version:
    3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 17:39:04) [GCC 10.3.0]
sys.executable: /home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/bin/python3.1
os.name: posix
sys.platform: linux


### error information


An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/bin/python3.1', '-mvirtualenv', '/home/name/.cache/pre-commit/repolk_aet_q/py_env-python3.1', '-p', 'python3.1')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.1'
    
stderr: (none)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/error_handler.py", line 73, in error_handler
    yield
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/main.py", line 361, in main
    return hook_impl(
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/hook_impl.py", line 238, in hook_impl
    return retv | run(config, store, ns)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/run.py", line 414, in run
    install_hook_envs(to_install, store)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 223, in install_hook_envs
    _hook_install(hook)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 79, in _hook_install
    lang.install_environment(
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/languages/python.py", line 219, in install_environment
    cmd_output_b(*venv_cmd, cwd='/')
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pre_commit/util.py", line 146, in cmd_output_b
    raise CalledProcessError(returncode, cmd, retcode, stdout_b, stderr_b)
pre_commit.util.CalledProcessError: command: ('/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/bin/python3.1', '-mvirtualenv', '/home/name/.cache/pre-commit/repolk_aet_q/py_env-python3.1', '-p', 'python3.1')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.1'
    
stderr: (none)
```

### Workaround

This error is evaded if I remove the `/home/name/anaconda3/envs/networkx-to-lava/bin/python3.1` file. However, that breaks automation and seems to be an improper work-around.

### Question

How can I ensure creating and activating the Conda environment allows direct running of the pre-commit hook without error (without having to delete the `python3.1` file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is unfortunately a known bug in `conda` -- though I'm unfamiliar with the status on it.  they're mistakenly shipping a `python3.1` binary as the default executable (it should be called `python3.10` -- they have a [2020](https://github.com/asottile/flake8-2020) problem that's probably a `sys.version[:3]` somewhere)

fortunately, you can instruct pre-commit to ignore its "default" version detection (which is detecting your `python3.1` executable) and give it a specific instruction on which python version to use

there's two approaches to that:

1. [`default_language_version`](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-default_language_version): as a "default" which applies when `language_version` is not set

```yaml
default_language_version:
    python: python3.10  # or python3

# ...
```

2. [`language_version`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-language_version) on the specific hook (to override whatever default value the hook provider has set)

```yaml
# ...

    -   id: black
        language_version: python3.10
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: This was definitely fixed - upgrade Conda.

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you for this detailed answer, I verified solution 1. works. 

Ps. I think `pre-commit` is magnificent, I am just configuring it and setting up the `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. I like it a lot already and I think it's an awesome concept! Thanks for the suggestion merv.

Answer (score 1):

There was a ticket opened regarding the observation in pre-commit repository https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1375

One of pre-commit contributers suggest to use `language_version: python3` for black config in `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3
```

https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1375#issuecomment-603906811